# Pergunta duplicada, ganha medalha

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Eu não sei se isso é um bug, mas pergunta duplicada ganha medalha por visitas:

[PERGUNTA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142130/url-amigavel-automatica-em-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, problema algum nisso. Se tem muitas visitas está cumprindo o objetivo de ser localizado nos mecanismos de busca e mesmo que ali não tivesse um resposta, seria a porta de entrada para a pergunta com uma resposta boa.

Eu sou um pouco contra dar reputação para perguntas duplicatas, na verdade pouco deveria dar reputação para perguntas, distorce o sentido de reputação, mas medalha por atrair visitas é legal sim, devia ter mais disso.

Comment: Servem de "sinônimos" de título basicamente. Entendi.